# Appearance of sets on characters ingame

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there any resource for how characters look when wearing a complete set? I am specifically interested in Captain Crimson's Attire or Aughild's Treasured on a male Barbarian, but would prefer a general answer for all sets & characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.diablowiki.net/File:Aughildstreasured_allclasses.jpg shows Aughild's Treasured set on each class, though not of both genders.

Comment: Thanks - accepting this, was looking for a comprehensive resource for all classes but this is the only useful info :)

Comment: http://www.diablowiki.net/Captain_Crimson%27s_Attire has the same type of images for Captain Crimson's Attire.  At the bottom of that page are links to other sets with similar images.